# I want to Change Color of 'No Results' in Searchdisplaycontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I want to change color of **No Results** in search controller. I can change the search table background color separate indexcolor.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

create a property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController * searchController;
```

then add following:

```
// When the user types in the search bar, this method gets called.
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)aSearchController {

//// .. do whatever your search results..

     for (UIView *subview in ((UITableViewController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController).tableView.subviews) {
         if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            if ([((UILabel *)subview).text isEqualToString:@"No Results"]) {
               ((UILabel *)subview).textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            }
         }
      }
}
```

Edited Ans:

```
for (UIView *subview in self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            if ([((UILabel *)subview).text isEqualToString:@"No Results"]) {
                ((UILabel *)subview).textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how you implemented **UISearchController**? Is it like this `[[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController]`?

Comment: I use it like" self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView"

Comment: Updated ans, check it n let me know

Comment: you are welcome, accept the ans and vote it if you want to support me :)